# Using WebDriver, how do I select an option in a field tagged with ejs-dropdownlist on a web page built in Angular?

Tags: angular, selenium, webdriver, dropdown

After struggling with this question for a while I found a solution.

The `ejs-dropdownlist` tag is on a web page that is being developed using Angular.

Here is the full XPath of the dropdown I'm trying to select from:

```
`/html/body/app-root/div[1]/app-header/header/div[2]/ejs-dropdownlist/span`
```

Notice that there is no `select` tag. Also, although the field has an id, it appears to be dynamically indexed, since it's different every time I open the page in a new browser.

I cannot capture or open the xpath for the options list dropdown, because when I try, the options list immediately disappears on the next click made anywhere on the desktop, and so does the associated unexpanded html code.

My solution is to:

> Click on the field using the xpath:
>       `//app-header/header/div[2]/ejs-dropdownlist/span`
>
> Use `sendKeys()` on the same xpath with the exact spelling of the option being selected.
>
> Click on the white area nearby on the page.

Like this:

```
'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-header/header/div[2]/ejs-dropdownlist/span")).click();'
'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-header/header/div[2]/ejs-dropdownlist/span")).sendKeys("Baltimore");'
'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-header/header")).click();'
```

I do not use the full xpath starting with `/html/`, just the part that sufficiently identifies the dropdown list I want to exercise.

This is working for me finally. Are there suggestions for improving this?

Comment: Does the element have other attributes?

Answer (score 1):

If the element has other attributes you can get to them with something like:

Example html from this page:

```
<div class="user-details" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a href="/users/12560802/richard-g-valverde">Richard G Valverde</a><span class="d-none" itemprop="name">Richard G Valverde</span>
        <div class="-flair">
            <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will find the link with your name on this page using a combination of element attributes and text contains:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class']//a[contains(., 'Richard G Valverde')]")
```

If you know the text in the dropdown list you can search the page for that text with. The dropdown list should be displayed before running either of these.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Dropdown text I want')]")
```

Will return all the elements with that text in an array.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Dropdown text I want')]")
```

Will find the first element.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The thing is, with the ejs-dropdownlist, I cannot see the html code that contains the text I want to click on. The code is hidden. Otherwise, this would be straightforward.

Comment: Programmatically click the dropdown and save the html of the page with ----some_variable = driver.page_source ------  Now you will be able to see the html of the elements you are looking for when you print(some_variable).

Comment: @Richard G Valverde I added two ways to look for the dropdown option with the displayed text.